# Tensorflow build quantization tool - bazel build error

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, bazel, quantization

I am trying to compile the quantization script as described in [Pete Warden's blog](https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/). However I get the following error message after running the following bazel build:

```
bazel build tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools:quantize_graph
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools': BUILD       file not found on package path.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.277s
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what happened is that this quantization tool got moved out of contrib and into TensorFlow core. You should be able to use that instead:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it.

Comment: After I got this working the next command is :
    `bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools/quantize_graph \
--input=/tmp/classify_image_graph_def.pb \
--output_node_names="softmax" --output=/tmp/quantized_graph.pb \
--mode=eightbit`

However I get this error:

    `Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter`
from there.

Got any idea on this? (I ran this in my tensorflow root directory)

Comment: I think it's the same cause. Try `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph  \ --input=/tmp/classify_image_graph_def.pb \ --output_node_names="softmax" --output=/tmp/quantized_graph.pb \ --mode=eightbit`

Comment: Well, that's what I am running (I just copied the example from Pete's blog here although I am running the bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph)  and it shows that it founds it and run it. The error that I am geting is related to some python code useed internally by quantize_graph here is the full output with error message: (next comment)

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moazzami/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph.py", line 34, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf ...`

`Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.`

Comment: Hmm. I just cloned the TensorFlow repository again, ran `./configure`, `bazel build tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph`, and `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph --input=/tmp/classify_image_graph_def.pb --output_node_names="softmax" --output=/tmp/quantized_graph.pb --mode=eightbit`, and it runs with just a couple deprecation warnings and seems to work. Maybe try that?

Comment: I think the issue that I have is that TF is somewhat confused between my Anocanda python and the python i have installed on my machine! - I guess ..

Comment: Yup, that was it, reconfiguring TF with right python address solved the issue. Thank you very much for your helps @Allen